# Coolpad note 3 lite stuck in recovery mode. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: adb

I have an Coolpad Note 3 lite which is stuck in recovery mode. I am getting a "no command" error. The USB debugging of phone is disabled. Wiping off data and factory reset using recovery mode does not work. Also, the flashtool does not do anything. The phone is soft bricked, SO, help me guys.The details of my phone are:

[Phone details](http://www.gizmotimes.com/smartphones/os-updates/coolpad-note-3-marshmallow-update-ui-release-date-leaked/10824)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the `SP Flash tool` downloaded from here:
http://spflashtool.com/

Download `coolpad note 3 lite stock ROM` from here
[*removed dead link, do a Google search*]

> Important: Make sure you have your battery charged to at least 60% before executing these steps to reduce the chances of bricking your device.

Now follow these steps:

1. Extract the ROM zip.
2. Run SP Flash Tool.
3. Click on `scatter-loading` , Browse and select the scatter txt file from the extracted ROM zip.
4. Click on the `download` buton
5. turn off your device and connect to PC.
6. This should start flashing the ROM to your phone.
7. Wait till you get a `Download OK` dialog box.
8. Now disconnect your phone & reboot.It'll be stuck in Fastmmi mode with "Up Down" written on screen.
9. Download `Minimal ADB and Fastboot Tool` and install.
10. Launch `Minimal ADB and Fastboot Tool`
11. Type in `adb devices` and make sure your device is listed.

> If it's not listed, then make sure your device is connected properly and/or reboot your PC.

12. Type in `adb shell fctest system reboot`

> If everything goes well, your phone should be unbricked now.

*Note: If any of the links are down, a simple google search should bring you the required files.*

Courtesy:

1. Guide
   http://www.anythingultimate.in/2015/11/how-to-flash-stock-romunbrick-coolpad.html
2. Stock ROM
   http://www.coolpadforums.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=457